# CListCtrl Update ScrollBar issue

Tags: c++, mfc, scrollbar

I tried to update a CLstCtrl by deleting all items and insert it. But the scrollBar go on top after each refresh.

```
int nIndex;
m_list.SetRedraw(FALSE);
m_list.DeleteAllItems();

nIndex = m_list.InsertItem(0, "toto");  
...
nIndex = m_list.InsertItem(50, "toto");

m_list.SetRedraw(TRUE);
```

It tried to use `int iScroll = m_list.GetScrollPos(SB_VERT);` and restore the position using `m_list.Scroll(CSize(0, iScroll));` but it doesn't work.

I see that `m_list.EnsureVisible(nItem, FALSE);` can be used, but i haven't a selected item to set.

So, how can I restore ScrollBar position.
Thx for helping.

Comment: After deleting all items, your code only inserts a single item, why do you expect that the scroll bar position is something else than on top? There isn't anything to scroll to.

Comment: It's just a sample code, i insert enought items to see the scrollbar

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of what you want and another of what you actually get?

Comment: OK, the sample is better now. I still don't understand, why you can't use `EnsureVisible`.

Comment: You could also try `m_list.SetScrollPos(SB_VERT, iScroll); m_list.SendMessage(WM_VSCROLL, MAKEWPARAM(SB_THUMBPOSITION, iScroll), 0);` (the call to `SetScrollPos` is required because `WM_VSCROLL` can only pass 16-bit scroll position)

Comment: This sounds like you actually want to change/update items, but instead go for delete all/insert all. If you simply update all items, the scrollbar position remains unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Call `list.EnsureVisible(list.GetItemCount() - 1, TRUE)` to go to the bottom of the list, then call `list.EnsureVisible(topindex, TRUE)` to make sure `topindex` appears on top. See example below.

Note that I used `SetRedraw(BOOL)` instead of `list.SetRedraw(BOOL)`, otherwise this method doesn't work properly when listview is in List mode.

```
int topindex = list.GetTopIndex();
SetRedraw(FALSE);

list.DeleteAllItems();
insert();

if(topindex >= 0)
{
    list.EnsureVisible(list.GetItemCount() - 1, TRUE);
    list.EnsureVisible(topindex, TRUE);
}

SetRedraw(TRUE);
list.Invalidate(TRUE);
```